# How to differentiate between server errors and integrity constraint exceptions when using RPC?

Tags: java, gwt

I have this method on the server side talking communicating with the client side code through RPC.

```
@Override
public void registerStudent(param1, param2...) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    //some code here

    try {
        //some code here
    } catch (ConstraintErrorViolationException e) {
        throw new RegisterFailedException();
    }
}
```

I have this chunk of code handling failures.

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
    displayErrorBox("Could not register user", caught.getMessage());
}
```

Currently, the `onFailure()` function does not differentiate between random exceptions and the specific exception I am looking to deal with and handle, which is `RegisterFailedException`.

How can I successfully handle the two different sort of errors properly?

Comment: I can edit the question to provide more detailed codes for the registerStudent() function if needed. I thought it was best to avoid posting unnecessary code which will clutter up the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your exception

```
public class RegisterFailedException extends RuntimeException {

    public RegisterFailedException () {
        super();
    }
}
```

and your method  throws the exception like

```
throws new RegisterFailedException();
```

Then in  `onFailure()`  check

```
if (caught instanceof RegisterFailedException){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `RegisterFailedException` is part of the client packages, you can simply use `instanceof`:

```
if(caught instanceof RegisterFailedException) {
   // handle RegisterFailedException
} 
else {
  // handle other exceptions
}
```